# Using Document Reference Type with Flutter, Provider and Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I'm using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), and [Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/) to get some documents that are using the `Document Reference Type` in their data model

Is there a good way to get both the data and the nested references in the same "Widget building" pass?

I can retrieve the data, and I can build my classes and widgets from the data, but I'm not able to to update the widgets after I retrieve the referenced documents.

A data model for the object in question would look like this:

```
{
    name: "Check name",
    modifiers: [1, 2 ,3],
    stats: [stat_reference_one, stat_reference_two]
}
```

Where `stat_reference_one` is a path and the reference type. And it's path is: `"/users/.../.../checks/:id"`

In my data service I have the following code:

```
class DataService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Check>> getChecks() {
    var ref = _db.collection(
        "/users/.../.../checks/");

    return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) {
          Map _a = doc.data() as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

          var _alternatives = _a['rollAlternatives']['default'];

          List _s = _alternatives['stats'];

          List<Stat> SS = [];
          _s.forEach((e) => getStat(e.parent.path, e.id).listen((Stat event) {
                SS.add(event);
              }));

          return Check.fromFirestore(doc, statList: SS);
        }).toList());


  Stream<Stat> getStat(String parentPath, String docId) {
    return _db
    .collection(parentPath)
    .doc(docId)
    .get()
    .asStream()
    .map((doc) => Stat.fromFirestore(doc));
  }
```

There you can see I have two builders a`Stat.fromFirestore` and a `Check.fromFirestore`

```
class Stat {

  ...

  Stat(this.name, this.value);

  ...

  factory Stat.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data() as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
    return Stat(
      data['name'],
      data['value'],
    );
  }
}
```

So, the `getChecks` method consumes `getStat` and therefore `Stat` before trying to create a new `Check` object instance. But at the moment it creates the `Check` object the stream for `Stat` has not finished yet. So my widget is drawn with just the constant values from the `modifiers` field. And it's not until I change screen that I see the widget rendered with the result from the `stats` field, so it works, but it's not rendered "on time"

Is there a good way to solve for this? I could turn `getStat` into a future, but then I wouldn't get the data on stream, which is something I need.

Maybe there's a way to wait for the stream to solve and then return the result of `getChecks` I tried to use the `onDone` parameter of listen, but that that has a type signature of void.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

When working with more streams nested to each other, it's wise to use packages like RxDart. Which will ease and smooth your program.
https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

You should definately check out, according to your explanation switchLatest function would do the job for you.
https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/switchLatest.html

Let me know if you got questions.